# FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, http, web

I'm building an online store with a cart feature via NodeJS (ExpressJS) and Firebase Database. When I click "Add to Cart" I get an error message that `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Operating System: `Windows 11`.
IDE: `Webstorm 2020.1`
Platform: `NodeJS` and `ExpressJS`.
Database Platform: `Realtime Firebase`.

This is the code:

```
router.post("/cart", (req, res, next) => {
    const uid = req.cookies.UID;
    const itemId = req.body.productId;

    onValue(ref(database, "users/" + uid), (snapshot) => {
        if(snapshot.exists()) {
            let user = snapshot.val();
            let cart = user.cart;

            if(!cart) cart = [];

            let index = cartIncludes(cart, itemId);

            if(index == -1) {
                cart.push({ id: itemId, amount: 1});
            }
            else {
                cart[index].amount += 1;
            }

            set(ref(database, "users/" + uid + "/cart"), cart);
            res.redirect("/cart");
        }
        else {
            res.redirect("/");
        }
    });
});
```

The function `cartIncludes` is just for validating.

This is the error message:

```
[2022-07-24T01:01:29.273Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at new View (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:94:20)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\routes\index.js:58:11
    at CallbackContext.onValue (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.node.cjs.js:12493:31)
    at C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.node.cjs.js:13349:46
    at exceptionGuard (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.node.cjs.js:674:9)
    at eventListRaise (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.node.cjs.js:11316:13)
    at eventQueueRaiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.node.cjs.js:11291:17)
    at eventQueueRaiseEventsAtPath (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.node.cjs.js:11263:5) 
C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.node.cjs.js:685
            throw e;
            ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at new View (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:94:20)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\routes\index.js:58:11
    at CallbackContext.onValue (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.node.cjs.js:12493:31)
    at C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.node.cjs.js:13349:46
    at exceptionGuard (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.node.cjs.js:674:9)
    at eventListRaise (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.node.cjs.js:11316:13)
    at eventQueueRaiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.node.cjs.js:11291:17)
    at eventQueueRaiseEventsAtPath (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\store\node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.node.cjs.js:11263:5)
```

Since the file `index.js` is detailed in the error message, I'll include it in this post:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  const uid = req.cookies.UID;

  onValue(ref(database, "users/" + uid), (snapshot) => {
    let logDiv, cartDiv;
    let btn_dis = "";

    if(snapshot.exists()) {
      logDiv = logoutDiv;
      cartDiv = _cartDiv;
    }
    else {
      logDiv = loginRegDiv;
      cartDiv = "";
      btn_dis = 'disabled="disabled"';
    }

    let productsDiv = "";

    onValue(ref(database, "products"), (snapshots) => {
      snapshots.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        const childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        const childData = childSnapshot.val();

        let title = childData.title;
        let description = childData.description;
        let price = childData.price;
        let id = childKey;

        productsDiv += `<div class="outer"><div class="content animated fadeInLeft"><h4>${title}</h4><p id="desc">${description}</p><a>${price}$</a><div class="button"><form action="/cart" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="productId" value="${id}"><button type="submit" ${btn_dis}>ADD TO CART</button></form></div></div></div>`;
      });

      res.render("index", { logDiv, cartDiv, productsDiv });
    });
  });
});
```

I tried to search at as many places as possible, including this site, but I didn't find any solution that helped me to solve this issue. Did I miss something important? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't `res.redirect("/cart");` but return a response... eg. the current contents of the cart.